# App working well in development, but fails when generating release APK

Tags: react-native

My app is working well in development mode but fails to generate the release APK. I don't know if that has something to do with the `appcompat-v7` or the buildTools versions or something else...maybe you can help me!

Here is my assebleRelease output:

```
.
.
.
> Task :react-native-languages:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac 
Note: /Users/xpto/Desktop/react-native/Movtour/node_modules/react-native-languages/android/src/main/java/com/reactcommunity/rnlanguages/RNLanguagesModule.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

> Task :react-native-maps:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
/Users/xpto/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/935d0f5835968768ce4a171dfc580369/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

/Users/xpto/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/935d0f5835968768ce4a171dfc580369/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

/Users/xpto/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/935d0f5835968768ce4a171dfc580369/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.

/Users/xpto/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/935d0f5835968768ce4a171dfc580369/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

/Users/xpto/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/935d0f5835968768ce4a171dfc580369/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

/Users/xpto/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar/935d0f5835968768ce4a171dfc580369/res/values/values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

error: failed linking references.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-bluetooth-status:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 22s
254 actionable tasks: 240 executed, 14 up-to-date
```

Follows next my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-beacons-manager')
    compile project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    compile project(':react-native-languages')
    compile project(':react-native-fs')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile project(':react-native-exit-app')
    compile project(':react-native-bluetooth-status')
    compile project(':react-native-device-info')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile (project(':react-native-maps')){
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

and my buildscript ext:

```
buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
minSdkVersion = 16
compileSdkVersion = 27
targetSdkVersion = 27 
supportLibVersion = "27.1.1"
```

Hope you can solve my problem! Thank you!

Comment: Run with --info and see what additional information comes up.

Answer (score 0):

I end up solving my problem by following this comment:
https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain/issues/153#issuecomment-425296990

I don't know how but if someone wants to explain the reason I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in last code android/build.gradle

```
subprojects {  // <-- Add this line
afterEvaluate {project ->
    if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 31
            buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'
        }
    }
}
```

}